# Executable Script file to Application

Tags: shell

I have a script file. I have made it executable by giving chmod +x permission. I want an application icon ... Clicking on that icon will run the script and the file gives output.
How can I do that ?

How can I make it an application?

Comment: You didn't mention, or add tag for your operating system, or show your script, or say how/what it outputs, nor what should happen to the output when you double-click it and there's no Terminal to send output to.

Answer (score 0):

```
To make a script file an application with an icon, you can create a desktop file. A desktop file is a text file that contains information about an application, such as its name, icon, and executable command.

To create a desktop file, follow these steps:

Open a text editor and create a new file.

Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=YourAppName
Exec=/path/to/script.sh
Icon=/path/to/icon.png

Replace /path/to/script.sh with the path to your script file.

Replace /path/to/icon.png with the path to the icon file that you want to use for your application.

Save the file with a .desktop extension. For example, myapp.desktop

Place the desktop file in the ~/.local/share/applications directory. 

This is the directory that desktop applications are typically installed to.

Once you have created the desktop file, you will be able to launch your application by clicking on the icon in the application menu.
```